# Estimating size of effects with either ANOVA or mixed model

Tags: regression, anova, mixed-model

I have a 2^4 full factorial study with 5 replicates and with several continuous dependent variables, but only 2 of the four independent variables are continuous. The other two include one variable that is off or on, and another that is high or low but does not have a good way to make it more continuous. Is it possible to estimate the size of the effects of the independent variables on the dependent ones?

Comment: What’s wrong with fitting a regression and using the parameter estimates?

Comment: A 2 ^ 4 factorial design wouldn't have continuous independent variables.  But also, there's no reason why you can't have dichotomous independent variables.  To get a reasonable answer, you may need to clarify the question, or be sure you haven't switched "dependent" and "independent" somewhere in the question.

Comment: I'm probably confused with my vocab here. Where can I find information on getting the parameter estimates?

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to see is something that will give me an idea of how big each significant effect is in comparison to each other.